# Access "My Info" from iOS app

Tags: ios, contacts, addressbook, avatar

I'm developing an iOS app for my employers. This app receives data that is always linked to phone numbers. Right now I've implemented a search function that takes the phone number and searches your contacts, retrieves the contact if any with that phone number and displays it's photo... like an avatar.

I've seen that Siri let's you chose a contact for "Your Information". Is there a way to access this specific contact from an iOS app ?

I mean this option point: Settings - General - Siri - My Info

Regards and thank you very much =)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this. You could just show the contact list and tell the user to choose themselves.

Comment: I finally just take the phone number of the user and search the AdressBook for it :)